# How to find the sum of values in hashmap in a file

Tags: java

This is my code

```
for (String k : word1.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(k + "\t" + word1.get(k));
    //int c+=word1.get(k);
}
System.out.println(word1.size());
```

The output of this code is

```
 Photos         0.6337632198238539
 software       0.20454545454545456
 service        0.09090909090909091
 applications  -0.20391337869173334
```

The commented line shows error. help me!!!

Comment: Show us whole code and exception

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Change `c` to `double` and move the declaration to outside the loop.

Comment: You're forcing them to guess at what error you had.  The output doesn't come from the code posted.  Also, how exactly is this "in a file"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to declare the variable to hold the sum before the loop.   Second, the numbers are clearly not integer, so you need to declare the sum accordingly:

```
double total = 0.0;
for (String k : word1.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(k + "\t" + word1.get(k));
    total += word1.get(k);
}
```

(This is assuming that the values are double, e.g. if you map is declared as

```
Map<String,Double> word1
```

**UPDATE:** As your map is declared as `Map<String, String>`, you'll need to convert values to double:

```
double total = 0.0;
for (String k : word1.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(k + "\t" + word1.get(k));
    try {
        total += Double.valueOf(word1.get(k));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // count the value as 0 if cannot convert to a double
    }
}
```

Comment: i have declared as map<String,String>

Comment: i have declared as map<String,String> because initially i had two words in the map like phone good software fast. Then assigned values for good fast and so on for the entire set of words. so it is a compatibility error now. how to resolve it!

Answer (score 1):

That you declared map as `Map<String, String>` is really something to mention in the question not just in a comment.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Photos", "0.6337632198238539");
        map.put("software", "0.20454545454545456");
        map.put("service", "0.09090909090909091");
        map.put("applications", "-0.20391337869173334");

        double c = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String k = entry.getKey();
            String v = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println(k + "\t" + v);
            c += Double.parseDouble(v);
        }
        System.out.println("===");
        System.out.println("Total: " + c);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Photos  0.6337632198238539
software    0.20454545454545456
service 0.09090909090909091
applications    -0.20391337869173334
=== 
Total: 0.7253043865866661
```

This is why I hate using `\t`.  Tabs are a pain.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is initializing the count inside the loop. It should be outside. It should also be a double if the map holds Double values.

```
double c = 0.0;
for (String k : word1.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(k + "\t" + word1.get(k));
    if (words1.get(k) != null)
        c += word1.get(k);
}
```

Now, if you are getting an exception, your map may contain null values. If that's the case, add a null check as in the code above.

Comment: A map cannot normally contain a null value.  You'll get an `IllegalArgumentException` if you try to put `null` into a map.

Comment: @AleksG It cannot contain a null key, but usually it can contain a null value.

Comment: @Eran Depends entirely on the map implementation.  java.util.HashMap goes to a lot of trouble to make sure you can use null as a key.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, Double> map = ...

double sum = 0.0;
for (Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "\t" + entry.getValue());
    sum += entry.getValue();
}
```